# Throwing an error is causing a 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning'

Tags: typescript, express, promise

I've got an async function:

```
public async postSomething(something: any): Promise<any> {
   try {
      const query: string = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES stuff';
      return await database.one(query);
   } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`Error posting request: ${error}`);
   }
}
```

Which I think should work alright, but when I call the method it works successfully and returns a 200, but I still get an error 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning' - originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch()...

I'm not entirely sure what I am doing wrong here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `works successfully` means the method returns result of `database.one(query)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside an async function, `throw`ing an error results in the Promise returned by the function to reject.

In your `catch`, although you properly catch the `database.one` Promise if it rejects, by re-throwing an error, you cause the Promise returned by `postSomething` to reject.

Either `.catch` in the caller of `postSomething`:

```
postSomething()
  .catch((error) => {
    res.status(500).send(error.message);
  });
```

Or don't re-throw in `postSomething`:

```
public async postSomething(something: any): Promise<any> {
   try {
      const query: string = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES stuff';
      return await database.one(query);
   } catch (error) {
      console.log(`Error posting request: ${error}`);
   }
}
```